# Default commit comment for magit

Tags: magit, git

Is there a simple way to have default text pre-populate in the comment buffer when commiting code with magit?

Comment: Are you looking for some static piece of text that is the same for every commit? Or something derived from the staged changes in some way?

Comment: @qhfgva could you please help us help you by answering our questions. Or does one of existing answers already address your issue? Then you should accept it.

Answer (score 7):

If what you're looking for, is a default template message for a commit, you can put this in your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[commit]
    template = /path/to/a/.gitcommitmessagetemplate.txt
```

And inside .gitcommitmessagetemplate.txt, put whatever you want, example:

```
type scope: subject

Body

Breaking changes with description of the change, justification
and migration notes.
Closes|Refs #
```

Answer (score 5):

You want `magit-commit-add-log`, probably.

1. navigate to a staged hunk
2. call `magit-commit-add-log`. It used to be bound to <kbd>C</kbd>. You'll get
   a Changelog-style entry related to the current hunk's function in the commit message.

Comment: Could you expand on that answer, maybe with a working example?